# Page truncate in right side for landscape orientation with trimmargins using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am talking about PdfSharp. Portrait orientation works well with margin or without margin. But In case of landscape orientation, page truncate in right side once I set any margin using TrimMargins. I have tried same thing on sample code of pdfSharp and having same problem!!

Look pdf rendered well for following code

```
page = document.AddPage();
page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
gfx.DrawString("A4 (landscape)", font,XBrushes.DarkRed, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),XStringFormats.Center);
```

But for following code pdf is not rendered well, truncate in right side

```
page = document.AddPage();
page.TrimMargins.Top = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Right = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Bottom = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Left = 5;
page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
gfx.DrawString("A4 (landscape)", font,XBrushes.DarkRed, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),XStringFormats.Center);
```

Have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug of PdfSharp

We can set the margins with orientation like bellow

```
page = document.AddPage();
//page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
XSize size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
if(page.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
{
   page.Width  = size.Height;
   page.Height = size.Width;
}
else
{
   page.Width  = size.Width;
   page.Height = size.Height;
}

// default unit in points 1 inch = 72 points
page.TrimMargins.Top = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Right = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Bottom = 5;
page.TrimMargins.Left = 5;
```

Answer (score 5):

Could be a bug in PDFsharp.

As a workaround, do not set the orientation to Landscape, instead swap width and height when creating the page.

```
page = document.AddPage();
//page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
XSize size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
page.MediaBox = new PdfRectangle(new XPoint(0, 0), new XPoint(size.Height, size.Width)); // Magic: swap width and height
//page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
```

The default unit for margins is Points.
To get e.g. millimetres instead, you can write:

```
page.TrimMargins.Top = XUnit.FromMillimeter(5);
page.TrimMargins.Right = XUnit.FromMillimeter(5);
page.TrimMargins.Bottom = XUnit.FromMillimeter(5);
page.TrimMargins.Left = XUnit.FromMillimeter(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem -- very frustrating. To anyone whom the top solution didn't work: try this!

Since PDFSharp can only handle graphics and transformations properly on pages in portrait orientation, my work-around on my project was converting the landscape pages to *portrait* with `.page.Rotate = 0` upon input. Remember that these files are now sideways so keep that in mind when applying graphics and transformations. Then before saving the file, I converted the page back to landscape with `.page.Rotate = 90`. Worked fine for me! Good luck y'all.