# Printing user control cuts off half an inch on top and left

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I've got a custom control that I'm trying to print. I've tried changing the margin's on my window to "indent" my control, but it still cuts off the left and top. I've also tried the following in my print method:

```
private void bttnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl hddc = HDDC;

    var printDlg = new PrintDialog
        {PrintTicket = {PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape, PageBorderless = PageBorderless.Unknown}};

    //printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName = PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmerica11x17;

    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {

        printDlg.PrintVisual(hddc, "HDDC Report");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Print Canceled");
    }
}
```

Still, no joy. I've got the feeling there's a silly setting I'm missing, but I just can't seem to find it. Why is my print cutting off on the top and left?

Comment: What happens if you alter the [PageScalingFactor?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.pagescalingfactor(v=vs.100).aspx) Not the answer but maybe a workaround to test.

Comment: What is your XAML? Is `HDDC` defined there like `<local:UserControl1 Name="HDDC" />`?

Comment: @blins: Actually, it's `<UserControls:HddcReport x:Name="HDDC" />`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the exact issue. I am printing to PDF and examining the result that way. I do see that I can get it to cutoff on the right if I simply drag the control to be large enough that it physically measures larger than the paper size but that is not quite what you describe as it still aligns to the top/left corner alright.

Comment: @Blins: If I do it to a PDF, it works fine, too. But when I print to a printer, that's when the cutoff happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Printing() {
   try {
     streamToPrint = new StreamReader (filePath);
     try {
       PrintDocument prd = new PrintDocument(); 
       prd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
       prd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
       // Set the page orientation to landscape.
       prd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
       prd.Print();
     } 
     finally {
       streamToPrint.Close() ;
     }
   } 
   catch(Exception ex) { 
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
 }
```

Namespace:  System.Drawing.Printing

or maybe this link can help u
[Page truncate in right side for landscape orientation with trimmargins using PdfSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948731/page-truncate-in-right-side-for-landscape-orientation-with-trimmargins-using-pdf)