# PDFSharp is cutting landscape pages with C# and WPF

Tags: c#, landscape, pdfsharp

thanks for take the time to read my odd issue with PDFSharp.

I use PDFSharp Library Version 1.50.4000.0 (I update from 1.3.2 and have the same issue) at the time to protect a PDF file with a password.

The program works very good with portrait documents but some times I have documents with mixed orientations.

But all the times when a landscape page it's in the document the page is cutted.

The code for your reference:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(System.IO.Path.Combine("H:/Bloq1/", file.Name), "PasswordHere");

                    PdfSecuritySettings securitySettings = document.SecuritySettings;
                    securitySettings.OwnerPassword = "PasswordHere";


                    securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
                    securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
                    securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
                    securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
                    securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = true;
                    securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = true;
                    securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = false;
                    securitySettings.PermitPrint = true;

                    document.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine("H:/Bloq1/", file.Name));

                    tbx.Text = "Complete";
                    tbx.Background = Brushes.ForestGreen;
```

Thanks in advance for your time reading or answering this question =D

*****************************Solved*********************************************

I switch to iTextSharp and test a couple of documents and works pretty well I'll share the code for reference:

```
private void Button_Full(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//PROTEGE PDF PERMITIENDO IMPRESION
    {
        string Password = "password";

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("H:/Bloq1/");

        if(dir.GetFiles("*.pdf").Length ==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no files in the default directory", "No Files", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            tbx.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
            tbx.Text = "No Files Found";
        }
        else
        {
            tbx.Background = Brushes.White;
            tbx.Text = "Protecting....";

            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
            {
                try
                {     
                    string InputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("H:/Bloq1/", file.Name);
                    string OutputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("H:/Bloq1/", "@"+file.Name);
                    using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        {
                            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
                            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);                                
                            PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, Password, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);                                 

                        }
                    }

                    file.Delete();
                    File.Move(@"H:\Bloq1\@"+file.Name, @"H:\Bloq1\"+file.Name);

                    tbx.Text = "Full Protected";
                    tbx.Background = Brushes.ForestGreen;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tbx.Text = "Error in: " + file.Name + ex;
                    tbx.Background = Brushes.IndianRed;

                }
            }
        }                      
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page truncate in right side for landscape orientation with trimmargins using PdfSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948731/page-truncate-in-right-side-for-landscape-orientation-with-trimmargins-using-pdf)

Comment: In the post that you link is rendering a new pdf I'm triying to protect a existing one, thanks for Reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch to iTextSharp and test a couple of documents and works pretty well I'll share the code for reference in the top.

Thank You to all

Answer (score 5):

For those that believe "I switched to iText" is not an answer, I've found a "fix" for PDFSharp.

Without diving into the source code PDFSharp appears to do a redundant rotation on landscape pages.  This corrected the landscape pages in documents I worked with that had both portrait and landscape pages.

```
PdfPages pageCollection = pdfDoc.Pages;
for (int i = 0; i < pageCollection.Count; i++)
{
    if (pageCollection[i].Orientation.ToString().Equals("Landscape"))
    {
        if (pageCollection[i].Rotate == 90)
        {
            pageCollection[i].Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer: It explains why it happens and a workaround

Answer (score 0):

If you use the source code version of PDFsharp you can make this change in PdfPage.cs to see if it solves your problem:

```
internal PdfPage(PdfDictionary dict)
    : base(dict)
{
    // Set Orientation depending on /Rotate.
    //int rotate = Elements.GetInteger(InheritablePageKeys.Rotate);
    //if (Math.Abs((rotate / 90)) % 2 == 1)
    //    _orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
}
```

I'd be glad to see feedback if you have to make further changes to get it working.

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9591#p9591

Comment: I switch to itextsharp because I don't have the source code versión =(, I'll share the code in the top, thanks for answer @ThomasH

Answer (score 0):

Since PDFSharp can only properly handle transformations on portrait pages, my work-around was converting the landscape pages to portrait with `.page.Rotate = 0` and then applying my transformations while accounting for that the page was now *sideways*. Before saving the file, I converted the page back to landscape with `.page.Rotate = 90`. Worked fine!

I had this *same* problem with my pages getting cut off. That's why its important to rotate the pages instead of directly changing the `Page.Orientation` attribute!